# How to define controller path in Laravel Package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to create a package with Laravel and Route my APIs to my package controllers. Without theirs Folder address.
So I need something like this:

```
Route::prefix('message')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'CustomMessageController@index');
});
```

And I fount somthing like this:

```
Route::prefix('message')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'Http/Controllers/CustomMessageController@index');
});
```

In addition I want to define all controller automatically in the ServiceProvider 'boot' method but i can find just somthing like this:

```
$this->app->make('Devdojo\Calculator\CalculatorController');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After a while I found it.
So the i do this:

1- Copy Laravel RouteServiceProvider to my package

2- rename it to my own Package Name

3- remove some unusable method and the finaly my RouteServiceProvider id following

```
<?php

namespace Alive2212\LaravelMessageService\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AliveLaravelMessageServiceRouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $namespace = 'Alive2212\LaravelMessageService\Http\Controllers';

    public function boot()
    {
    parent::boot();
    }

    public function map()
    {
    $this->mapApiRoutes();
    }

    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
    Route::prefix('alive_api')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(__DIR__.'/../../routes/api.php');
    }
}
```

4- register it into my Package Service Provider and finaly my package provider

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app->register(AliveLaravelMessageServiceRouteServiceProvider::class);
}
```

5- In root of package create 'route' folder and create api.php and put some Routes into it:

```
Route::prefix('message')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'CustomMessageController@index');
});
```

6- Create Folder 'Http\Controllers' into 'src' folder of package and put Controller.php from Laravel project and Create another controller into it somthing like this:

```
namespace Alive2212\LaravelMessageService\Http\Controllers;

use Alive2212\LaravelMessageService\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Alive2212\LaravelMessageService\Message;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CustomMessageController extends Controller
{
    protected $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->model = new Message();
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return "the is my package index controller";
    }

}
```

7- after serve project, "localhost:8000/alive_api/message" address work correctly

Answer (score 1):

You only need in your PackageServiceProvider.php

```
    public function register()
    {
        include __DIR__ . '/routes.php';
    }
```

And routes.php of course.

Comment: "You should never attempt to register any event listeners, routes, or any other piece of functionality within the register method." [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/providers)

Comment: I think this is related to non-package service providers. It was old way to publish routes. Maybe now the alternative is with mapping.